# Use WCF with Oracle and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf

it's possible to use WCF with Oracle when I'm importing data with these instructions ? :

```
OracleConnection oConnexion = new OracleConnection();
oConnexion.ConnectionString = "confidential";
oConnexion.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT...");
cmd.Connection = oConnexion;

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: How do you want WCF to fit in with this?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What do you want to do with WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) in this case? Do you want to transfer data from your database to a webservice?

Comment: I need to update my databases. So I want to send data with jQuery.ajax() to a webservice in ordert to update my databases ;)